# using runClasses(), JUnit tests not shutting down after timing out if test class is public

Tags: java, junit

It seems that `runClasses()` doesn't terminate the code being tested even after the test times out and fails.

An SSCCE:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;
import org.junit.runner.Result;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class<?>[] classes = { PublicTest.class };
        Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(classes);
        System.out.println("Num tests: " + result.getRunCount());
        System.out.println("Time: " + result.getRunTime());
        System.out.println("Failure: " + result.getFailures().get(0));
    }
}
```

Test class:

```
import org.junit.Test;

public class PublicTest {
    @Test(timeout=10)
    public void loop() {
        while(true) {}
    }
}
```

How do I get the code to terminate?

Comment: I'm using JUnit 4, more specifically: org.junit_4.8.2.v4_8_2_v20110321-1705

Comment: Waht is something? How did you see 'something'?

Comment: Two ways, I'm executing main from a jar file and it waits for the process to terminate.  It never* does. (I have it set to terminate the process after 5 minutes anyways.)  Also through eclipse, it shows the application is still running after printing out the results.

Comment: As for what it is, I have no idea, I'm assuming it's an errant thread because the code doesn't hang on the tests, they do timeout and the results get printed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JUnitCore at some point indeed does create a new thread that is never finishing. The main() implementation of JUnit avoids getting stuck by calling System.exit() when it has completed its work. That seems a little untidy to me, but might be the best solution for you.

Comment: This is a good idea, not sure why I didn't think of it.  However, like you said it isn't ideal and I'd still like to know exactly what's happening, is it a bug?

Comment: It has nothing to do with visibility, so I suppose it's expected behavior for `runClasses()`

Answer (score 1):

```
JUnitCore.runMainAndExit(new RealSystem(), DefaultTest.class.getName(), PublicTest.class.getName());
```

works well, tests are failured

Comment: I thought this was an acceptable answer but the API says do not use that method: [JUnit API](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/JUnitCore.html)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a package level class as a JUnit test. This explains the difference in behaviour. If I define `DefaultTest` to be a package class, then I get the following error from JUnit[*]:

```
Test class should have exactly one public constructor.
```

If I define a constructor, then I get

```
DefaultTest should be public.
```

JUnit tests need to be public because JUnit needs to instantiate the class.

So, if I have public DefaultTest and public PublicTest, then *neither* of the threads get terminated. This is normal behaviour for JUnit. It [calls Thread#interrupt()](https://github.com/KentBeck/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/internal/runners/statements/FailOnTimeout.java) (see evaluateStatement()). But your tests don't take any notice of this. JUnit doesn't force termination of the thread, so the thread continues running. For an explanation why, see [Thread#stop()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop%28%29).

So have your tests stop nicely, you need cooperation from them, such as:

```
@Test(timeout=10)
public void publicLoop() {
    while(!Thread.interrupted()) {
    }
}
```

This obviously may have consequences for your code under test as well. I'm sorry, I don't have an easy solution for that.

[*] Add the following line to your main():

```
System.out.println("failures=" + result.getFailures());
```

Comment: This is incorrect.  The default class level for java is package level, which is set by not having a modifier, [see this link.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)  Which is how I have it set in the SSCCE.  Another way to see that this is incorrect is to use JUnit without runClasses.  Finally this can also be shown by removing public from "PublicTest"; both tests terminate normally.  Given that visibility is the only difference between "DefaultTest" and "PublicTest" it is definitely an issue with visibility.

Comment: And if you remove public from PublicTest, how does it terminate? Does it terminate with failures? For me, it terminates with failures=[initializationError(DefaultTest): Class DefaultTest should be public, initializationError(PublicTest): Test class should have exactly one public constructor, initializationError(PublicTest): Class PublicTest should be public]. Try adding the printing of the failures. If I set both classes to be package level, then I get the same behaviour. If I set both to be public, then neither terminates correctly, like I said.

Comment: Test classes need to be public in JUnit. The reason you're getting a difference in behaviour is because the DefaultTest is terminating with a JUnit error. Your test isn't even being executed.

Comment: Yep, you're correct.  It doesn't have anything to do with visibility.  It seems that a timeout should cause junit to terminate. The test has already failed, why is it still running the code?  It terminates if you use `runMainAndExit()`.  But I think you may have pointed out to me how this could be seen as expected behavior, and that one of the other 2 solutions is what I'll have to go with.

Answer (score 1):

The following code helps:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private static void killStillRunningJUnitTestcaseThreads() {
    Set<Thread> threadSet = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
    for (Thread thread : threadSet) {
        if (!(thread.isDaemon())) {
            final StackTraceElement[] threadStackTrace = thread.getStackTrace();
            if (threadStackTrace.length > 1) {
                StackTraceElement firstMethodInvocation = threadStackTrace[threadStackTrace.length - 1];
                if (firstMethodInvocation.getClassName().startsWith("org.junit")) {
                    // HACK: must use deprecated method
                    thread.stop();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can be called just after `Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(classes);`

---

The same in a Java 8 stream API style:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private static void killStillRunningJUnitTestcaseThreads() {
    Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet().stream()
        .filter(thread -> !(thread.isDaemon()))
        .filter(thread -> Arrays.stream(thread.getStackTrace())
            .reduce((__, lastOnly) -> lastOnly)
            .map(StackTraceElement::getClassName)
            .map(className -> className.startsWith("org.junit"))
            .orElse(false))
        .forEach(Thread::stop);
}
```

Comment: That was the idea in my mind and when I started to implement it, I found your answer :D You saved me some time. Thanks :D :D

Answer (score 0):

I know this was a while ago but I started learning JUnit a few days ago and stumbled upon this same problem. I needed to be able to capture infinite loops, so the timeout annotation parameter was a partial solution, but I needed the test case that contained the infinite loop to complete executing - not hang. So I came up with this:

```
public class TestCase1 {
    @Test(timeout=100)
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("Test Case called");

        Thread myThread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("New thread created!");
                new InfiniteLoop().runLoop();
            }
        };

        myThread.start();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(101);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e) {

        }
        finally {
            myThread.stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Basically just launch the method that you're testing in its own thread, sleep for 1 millisecond over the defined timeout (so you make sure the test fails due to timeout), catch the interrupted exception thrown by JUnit and then kill the thread containing the infinite loop. Hope this helps someone.

Cheers,
Jay.

Answer (score 0):

Forcing the thread to stop is not the answer here. You could end up leaving expensive resources unreclaimed. E.g. if your test method actually spawned another process, that process would be left running. You need to write your test to be interruptible.

When a timeout expires, JUnit interrupts the thread that's executing the test. That, by itself, does not cause the thread to stop, since the whole interrupt mechanism in Java requires cooperation. It's intended as a means to request that a blocking or long-running operation stop earlier than it otherwise would.

Some blocking methods of `Thread` - like `Thread.sleep` and `Thread.wait` - will notice that they've been interrupted and will throw an `InterruptedException` when that happens. Your code can catch that exception and do what it wants. If it doesn't, it will exit just like it would with any other uncaught exception, and in that case, JUnit would catch it and report that your test failed due to an unexpected exception (unless, of course, you had configured your test to expect that exception). [In the case of a test with a timeout, JUnit would not actually report the uncaught exception - though it would still catch it. Instead it would report the timeout.]

If you don't do anything like a `Thread.sleep` or `Thread.wait` in your method, you'll never get an `InterruptedException` when JUnit interrupts the thread. But you don't need that to realize that a thread has been interrupted. Just call Thread#isInterrupted to find out (this has a side-effect of clearing the interrupted status on the thread). Then you can take whatever steps are needed to clean up and quit. Or not - it's your choice whether to cooperate!

For example, you could do something like this in your infinite-loop example:

```
import org.junit.Test;

public class PublicTest {
    @Test(timeout=10)
    public void loop() {
        while(true) {
           if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
               break;
           }
        }
    }
}
```